# Using Linq to XML foreach to create muliple XElements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm building an XML file dynamically using  new `XElement()`, and midway through the file creation I need to iterate over a set of child records and create `XElements` for them.  The problem I'm having is that I need to create more than 1 `XElement` per iteration.  This is a my loop:

```
from t in trans.SalesTransactionLines
select new XElement("text", new XAttribute("lang", "en"), t.ItemName)
```

This works fine, but I need an additional 'position' `XElement` before each 'text' Element.  This is the kind of thing I want, which doesn't work:

```
from t in trans.SalesTransactionLines
select new XElement("position",new XAttribute("x", "40"), new XAttribute("y", "420")),
new XElement("text", new XAttribute("lang", "en"), t.ItemName)
```

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
<position x="40" y="420" />
<text>Fender Classic Strat 70s Natural RN</text>
<position x="40" y="420" />
<text>Fender Classic 50s Tele White Blonde</text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method based syntax and `SelectMany` method instead:

```
trans.SalesTransactionLines.SelectMany(x => new[] {
                                                new XElement("position",
                                                    new XAttribute("x", "40"),
                                                    new XAttribute("y", 420")),
                                                new XElement("text",
                                                    new XAttribute("lang", "en"),
                                                    x.ItemName)
})
```

Comment: That looks like what I need, but where is 't' coming from?